# how to distinguish relationships between <-[r]-> and -[r]- in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I thought that in Cypher relationship "<-[r]->" means "<-[r]- AND -[r]->, while relationship "-[r]-" means "<-[r]- OR -[r]->". But they returned the same result.

```
start n=node(1), m=node(2) create n-[:no_direction]-m;
start n=node(1), m=node(2) create n-[:left]->m;
start n=node(1), m=node(2) create n<-[:both_direction]->m;

start n=node(1), m=node(2) match n-[r]-m return r;
start n=node(1), m=node(2) match n<-[r]->m return r;
```

Both "match n-[r]-m return r" and "match n<-[r]->m return r" return 3 records. I thought that "match n-[r]-m return r" should return 3 records, and "match n<-[r]->m return r" should only return one record.

How do I distinguish relationships between <-[r]-> and -[r]- in Cypher query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but I guess you're having some misunderstand on relationship's concepts here. A relationship in Neo4j is always directed, there's no exception from this rule.

In terms of querying you can disregard the fact that it's directed. Based on that the two statements are identical

```
start n=node(1), m=node(2) create n-[:RELTYPE]-m;
start n=node(1), m=node(2) create n<-[:RELTYPE]->m;
```

(the syntax `()<-[:TYPE]->()` is IMHO not even documented anywhere).

`MATCH n-[:RELTYPE]-m` means 'match any relationship having type RELTYPE in any direction (incoming or outgoing) between 1 and 2'.

In your example above if you get 3 results this just means that there are 3 relations of any type and any direction between node 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, the syntax "()<-[:TYPE]->()" is not documented anywhere, and A relationship in Neo4j is always directed. But the question is why Neo4j does not use "MATCH n<-[:RELTYPE]->m" to EXPLICITLY represent 'the relationship having type RELTYPE in Both direction (incoming AND outgoing) between 1 and 2'? "Both direction" is one type of direction.

Comment: the match statements represent a path, `n<-[:RELTYPE]->m` therefore stands for 2 nodes and 1 rel. If you want to match only of two relationships with different direction exist use `match n-[:TYPE]->m<-[:TYPE]-n`

Answer (score 1):

I would add to Stefan's correct answer that your line

```
start n=node(1), m=node(2) create n-[:no_direction]-m;
```

creates an INCOMING relationship from the first node's point of view, which might cause some confusion. This is just a default, since you provided no explicit direction and, as Stefan already said, relationships must be directed.